# Smoothstate.js and Django - Form POST only triggered on second click

Tags: jquery, django, smoothstate.js

Im currently trying to integrate Smoothstate.js into my Django Project.
I'm using the js code snippet from the smoothstate.js github site.

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var options = {
    prefetch: true,
    cacheLength: 2,
    onStart: {
      duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
      render: function ($container) {
        // Add your CSS animation reversing class
        $container.addClass('is-exiting');

        // Restart your animation
        smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
      }
    },
    onReady: {
      duration: 0,
      render: function ($container, $newContent) {
        // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
        $container.removeClass('is-exiting');

        // Inject the new content
        $container.html($newContent);

      }
    }
  },
  smoothState = $('#main').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

My template looks like this (I simplified it for this question):

```
<head>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/what-input.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/vendor/foundation.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/foundation.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" class="m-scene">
        <!--...-->
        <div class="row expanded collapse">
            <div class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinright large-12 columns">
                <a href="{% url 'transition' %}">test</a>
                <form action="{% url 'transition' %}" method='POST'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form}}
                    <input type="submit" class="button green" value="join"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.smoothState.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/initSmoothState.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

When I click on a link Smoothstate.js works like expected. But when I submit the form it doesn't send a post and just triggers the animations. When I click it a second time it sends the POST and works like it should.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've found those two issues on the smoothstate.js:
 [Issue #189](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/issues/189) and [Issue #231](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/issues/231)

Both are about the Problem, that if a `form POST action` points to the `same URI` the POST will never sent. When I set form caching to `true` I can recreate this behaviour.

When I set it to `false` and point the `POST action` to a `different URI` the `POST` will be sent like it should be. Setting it to the `same URI` without `form caching` brings me back to the original problem.

Is this a bug in Smoothstate.js? I can't see where this should come from django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question on the [smoothstate.js github page](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/issues/305).
It looks like the only solution to this is to blacklist the forms.

```
$('#main').smoothState({ blacklist: '.no-smoothState' });

<form class="no-smoothState">
  ...
</form>
```