# While using smoothstate.js submitting form causes smoothstate to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, smoothstate.js

I have site using smoothstate.js on every page. on a couple of pages, I have a modal box pop up with a form. Those forms work just fine.

On another page, I have a basic form included in the html. When I click the submit button on the form, the form actually submits but smoothstate starts which fades out the content and starts my loading screen.

I would like for that not to happen. Here is my smoothstate function:

```
$(function(){
    'use strict';
    var $page = $('#main'),
    options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 2,
        allowFormCaching: false,
        forms: 'form',
        blacklist: 'input[type="submit"], .animsition-loading, .hs-button',
        onStart: {
            duration: 1050, // Duration of our animation
            render: function ($container) {
                $('.animsition-loading').show();
                $container.addClass( 'slide-out' );
                smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 0,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                $container.html($newContent);
                sitejs();
                $(document).ready();
                $(window).trigger('load');
            }
        },
        onAfter: function( $container ) {
            $('.animsition-loading').hide();
            $container.removeClass( 'slide-out' );
        }
      },
      smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for me with a newsletter form. Here is the solution to your problem. You have to add the blacklisted class that you have in your JS (for example "no-smoothsate") to the FORM tag. It works perfectly.

```
<form class="no-smoothState">
...
</form>
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809205/smoothstate-js-and-django-form-post-only-triggered-on-second-click)

Answer (score 0):

I believe smoothstate is designed to work on forms as well as links by default, so as cf7 already works with AJAX you just need to blacklist as mentioned.

**For cf7 this is the code:**

```
;(function($) {
'use strict';

    var $body = $('html, body'),
    content = $('#main').smoothState({  
        blacklist: '.wpcf7-form',
        // Runs when a link has been activated
        onStart: {
            duration: 500, // Duration of our animation
            render: function ($container) {
                // Add your CSS animation reversing class
                $container.addClass('is-exiting');

                // Restart your animation
                smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 0,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                // Scroll user to the top, this is very important, transition may not work without this
                $body.scrollTop(0);

                // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
                $container.removeClass('is-exiting');

                // Inject the new content
                $container.html($newContent);

                // Trigger load functions
                $(document).ready();
                $(window).trigger('load');
            }
        },
        onAfter: function($container) {
            initContactForm();
        }
    }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```